# Randomized database field in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have a database called "test_gen" .. and have fields of "ID" and "Question" .

i would like to randomized my "Question" field in my listbox every time i click a button .. please help me with this !

thanks a lot
-neil

Answer (score 0):

Say, we have saved your database as an array.

```
Dim DB As String() = {"ID1;Question1", "ID2;Question2"}
```

We could then call this function and define wether we want the id or question

```
Private Enum GetOption
    Question
    ID
End Enum

Private Function GetQuestion(DB As String(), [option] As GetOption) As String
    Return DB(New Random().[Next](0, DB.Count())).Split(";"C)(If([option].Equals(GetOption.ID), 1, 0))
End Function


Button1.Click += New EventHandler(Function(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
Listbox1.Add(GetQuestion(DB, GetOption.ID))
End Function)
```